# Where do young wizards learn to read, write, do maths and do other basic things?

Tags: harry-potter, wizards

Harry, Hermione and other wizards with one or more muggle parents learned to read, write, do maths and more at elementary school. Do children from wizard families just learn this at home? And are there tests they have to pass?

Comment: I suspect they learn them from muggle teachers and that's why they don't go to wizard school until the age of eleven.

Comment: I'm not sure this does answer the question. We learn a lot of maths from age 11 and many other things. Are wizards only educated to primary school level in everything other than magic (possible, but really)?